# Converting documents at the same time

Tags: python, flask

This is my code:

```
@main.route('/convert', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def one():
        patch1 = somepatch
        patch2 = somepatch
        patch3 = somepatch
        
        zp = request.form.get("echeck1")
        zz = request.form.get("echeck2")
        dz = request.form.get("echeck3")
        
        if zz == 'on':
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(""""C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\\unoconv" -f pdf """ + patch1)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print(e)

        if dz == 'on':
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(""""C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\\unoconv" -f pdf """ + patch2)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print(e)

        if zp == 'on':
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(""""C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\\unoconv" -f pdf """ + patch3)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print(e)
        
        try:
            subprocess.check_call("taskkill /f /im  soffice.exe")
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print('error kill process'

        return redirect(url_for('main.work'))
```

The problem is that if more than one user starts executing this code at the same time, the unoconv process will crash. I don't understand why, because Flask is synchronous and before executing a request, it must wait for the previous one to finish. Is not it so?

Thats error when 2 users press the button at the same time:
unoconv: RuntimeException during disable-showchanges phase:
Office probably died. Binary URP bridge disposed during call

Comment: How is this being deployed?

Comment: _Flask is synchronous_ -- Why do you think that?

Comment: @Tim Roberts
because it is described in the documentation

Comment: It depends on how you're using it.  The internal development server is single threaded, but if you're running behind Apache or behind a uWSGI server, then you can have multiple threads at once.

Comment: @Tim Roberts 
I am not using apache or any other server, I am only using the internal wsgi Flask server. By calling the app.run function (host = "0.0.0.0", debug = False)

Comment: @noslenkwah this happens when 2 users press at the same time, if you press with a time interval, then everything is ok. But if you press at the same time, then the Flask function starts working for 2 users at the same time. It shouldn't, though, because Flask is synchronous.

Comment: The internal dev server is not meant to be used for production. It has lot of known shortcomings. But thats ok because its purpose is not to be used for deployment. IT sounds like you've found a limitation of the dev server (sounds like a race condition). While you might be able to figure out a work around for the dev server, it won't be of much use since you won't be deploying with the dev server. My suggestion would be to setup an environment with more of your stack (nginx, uwsgi, or whatever) and test it there.

Comment: see the [warning](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/server/) in the docs.

Comment: @noslenkwah   OK I'll try tomorrow and unsubscribe

Comment: @noslenkwah 
Hello againg ) . I deployed a bunch of apache + mode wsgi + flask, but the result is the same: (this is magic)